# How to cast cursorLoader to Loader<Object>

Tags: java, android, casting, android-loadermanager

Hopefully simple java question I've just forgotten or never understood.  I've been playing with Loaders in Android 4.0.  The program is working as was but now I'm looking to the 'next' part.  I want a standard Cursor loader and a custom AsyncTaskLoader.  I'm stuck on part 1 trying to convert a cursorLoader to a Loader and return it.

```
@Override
    //public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    public Loader<Object> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        if (id == LISTVIEWLOADER) {
            String[] projection = { RunnerTable.COLUMN_ID,
                    RunnerTable.COLUMN_NAME };
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    FanContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,
                    null);


            return cursorLoader;   //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Type mismatch cannot convert from CursorLoader to Loader.

I believe can make it work with

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment implements
        //LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
```

But don't like the warning:

LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks is a raw type. References to generic type LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks should be parameterized

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 30):

Even though this is an old thread, it has not yet been fully answered. The issue here was touched on by tch0106, but not fully described.

I just ran into the same issue and resolved it in the imports section. In simple terms: Use the support Loader, CursorLoader and LoaderCallbacks together.

Several classes can be found in both the android local libraries as well as the support libraries.  Don't mix the support libraries with the non-support library versions.

```
// Use these together
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

// Or use these, but don't mix and match
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```

Comment: This worked form me.  I mixed import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader with import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.  Thanks for helping me find this quickly.  Someone should mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

Check your import, you may mis use these 2:

```
import android.content.CursorLoader;
```

and

```
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your answer would be much more helpful if you highlighted how exactly these imports are misused.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public Loader<Object> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
```

to

```
  public Loader<? extends Object> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
```

First statement tells jvm, return type is concrete `Object`. New statement tells jvm that any TYPE which is of `Object`.

Please read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Comment: Afraid that still doesn't work.  The return type is incompatible with LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object>.onCreateLoader(int, Bundle).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, very similar to this one, by changing an import... I made the mistake, when I declared the custom loader.

```
// My custom loader java class:

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;  //this was the place of my mistake right here
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArticleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<Article>> {

    public ArticleLoader(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Article> loadInBackground() {
        ArrayList<Article> articles = QueryUtils.fetchArticles(getContext());
        return articles;
    }
}
```

So, what happened was that I didn't pay attention enough and Android Studio has auto-imported the 'android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader'.

Hope this helps someone!

Ton

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this:
[Android AsyncTaskLoader Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)

I believe your problem resides at this line:

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment implements
    //LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks
```

You should change to something like this:

```
public static class AppListFragment extends ListFragment
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<AppEntry>>
```